# How to break long word into new line in an inline-block div

Tags: html, css

I have the following example

The first and third example is correct to design, but i can't figure out a way to make the long word in example 2 to break the word correctly. Is there a way to do it only using CSS?

Update: I have tried using word-break, but it is not working on IE 10). Also is it worth to mention that in the third example should stay the way it is.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 2px solid rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  background-color: rgba(64, 72, 75, 0.14902);
}

.name {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
  background-color: rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  padding: 0px 7px; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 150px">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 300px">
  <div class="name">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add display:block; in your .name class

Comment: yes changing the display property from inline-block to block solve your issue.

Comment: You have 2 option for this opportunity:-

1) word-break:breal all;

2) display: inline-block; to display: block;

You can choose any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set *max-width* for your *inline-block* element.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 2px solid rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  background-color: rgba(64, 72, 75, 0.14902);
}

.name {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
  background-color: rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  padding: 0px 7px; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 14px); // 100% - padding
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 150px">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaae</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 300px">
  <div class="name">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But in the third example, the dark area must end just where the text end, this way the third example is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Add this property **word-break: break-word;** to you **.name** class

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 2px solid rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  background-color: rgba(64, 72, 75, 0.14902);
}

.name {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(64, 72, 75);
padding: 0px 7px;
/* word-wrap: break-word; */
display: inline-block;
word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 150px">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 300px">
  <div class="name">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add word-break: break-all; to .name class .. Thats it...

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 2px solid rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  background-color: rgba(64, 72, 75, 0.14902);
}

.name {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
  background-color: rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  padding: 0px 7px; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 150px">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 300px">
  <div class="name">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove  `display:inline-block;` and Add you can `display:block;`

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 2px solid rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  background-color: rgba(64, 72, 75, 0.14902);
}

.name {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
  background-color: rgb(64, 72, 75); 
  padding: 0px 7px; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 150px">
  <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaae</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="top: 300px">
  <div class="name">a</div>
</div>
```